# Add border to element while keeping parent element the same height

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to add a border to an element on hover while also keeping the parent `div` size the same.

Currently when I add the border it makes the parent `div` larger in height.

```css
nav {
  margin: 0px auto 1px auto;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav a:first-child {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  border-left: 1px white solid;
  border-right: 1px white solid;
  border-bottom: 1px white solid;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a transparent border to displace the one that is added on hover.

In this case, you could use:

```
nav a {
  border: 1px transparent solid;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```css
nav {
  margin: 0px auto 1px auto;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
}
nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px transparent solid;
  border-top: none;
}
nav a:first-child {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px white solid;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

### Method No. 1 - Give the `<a>` a transparent border:

```
nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 1px transparent solid;
  border-right: 1px transparent solid;
  border-bottom: 1px transparent solid;
}
```

### Method No. 2 - Give the `<nav>` a fixed height:

```
nav{
height:45px;
}
```

Comment: @BlakeWebb glad i could help :D Mark either mine, or Josh Crozier's answers as accepted by clicking the check mark beside them. He did answer a minute before me though :D